# Member initialization syntax in C++ constructors

Tags: c++, member-initialization

Why does the following not compile?

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int a) : a_{a} {}
    private:
        int a_;
};
```

Comment: You have a typo: `{a}` should be `(a)`

Comment: [It does too compile](https://godbolt.org/z/T9bWaors7). To the extent there is a problem, it must needs lie in the code not shown.

Comment: @fireshadow52 That is not a typo. It is correct. We can use `a_{a}`  in the contstructor initializer list in C++11 without any problem.

Comment: @AnoopRana Ah; right. I'm stuck in C++89...

Comment: Didn't realize I have to use the `-std=c++11`flag to force the compiler to use C++11.

Comment: @fireshadow52 you probably mean the 98th ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does the following not compile?

Because you're most probably compiling the shown code, with **Pre-C++11** standard version.

The curly braces around `a` in your example, is a C++11 feature.

To **solve** this you can either compile your program with a C++11(or later) version or use parenthesis `()` as shown below:

**Pre-C++11**

```
class A {
    public:
//-------------------v-v--------->note the parenethesis which works in all C++ versions
        A(int a) : a_(a) {}
    private:
        int a_;
};
```

**C++11 & Onwards**

```
class A {
    public:
//-------------------v-v------->works for C++11 and onwards but not with Pre-C++11
        A(int a) : a_{a} {}
    private:
        int a_;
};
```